# Generic parameter T could not be inferred , Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is my function declaration....

```
func requestApi<T:Codable>(_ url: URLConvertible,method:HTTPMethod = .post, parameters: Parameters, header:[String:String] ,completion:@escaping (_ success:Bool,_ result:T?) -> Void) {
    
    print("parameters: ",parameters)
    print("HEADERS: ",header)
    requestAPI(url, method:method,httpBody:parameters.queryString, headers: header) { (result:ApiResult<T,APIError>) in
        print(result)
        switch result {
        case .success1(let result):
            print(result)
            completion(true, result)
        case.failure(let error):
            DataHandler.shared.showAlert(title: "", message: error.customDescription)
            print(error.customDescription)
            completion(false, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I am calling this function.

```
UserStore.shared.requestApi(CUSTOMER_BOOKING_DETAILS, parameters: params, header: header) { (flag, result) in ...
```

And on function call I am getting this error "Generic parameter T could not be inferred , Issue"

Answer (score 0):

you should give type of result in completion block

```
UserStore.shared.requestApi(parameters: params, header: header) { (flag, (result as? CUSTOMER_BOOKING_DETAILS)) in ...
```